gnu ld linker script LONG() not placing value as expected (ARM Cortex-M3)
gnu .ld linker script --
I have added a MEMORY definition to hold a checksum:
_CRC_Value = 0x12345678;

MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 80K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 524285 /* to 0x0807FFFB inclusive, confusingly, this should be 524284, but that gives me the wrong offset in the .map file */
  CHECKSUM (rw)   : ORIGIN = 0x807FFFC,    LENGTH = 4
}

and defined a section as:
.crc :
{
  _Check_Sum = .; /* sets the address to ORIGIN of CHECKSUM */
  LONG(_CRC_Value);
} >CHECKSUM

my .map file shows me things should be aligned correctly (unless I misunderstand):
.crc            0x0807fffc        0x4
                0x0807fffc                        _Check_Sum = .
                0x0807fffc        0x4 LONG 0x12345678 _CRC_Value

In my main.c, I have defined this symbol:
uint32_t _Check_Sum __attribute__((section(".crc")));

However, I commented that out, since the linker is now actually defining the symbol, it doesn't seem necessary.  Regardless, I get the same results either way in the debugger, which is this...
Expression | Type     | Value      | Address
_Check_Sum | uint32_t | 1450704896 | 0x807fffc

Value 1450704896 = 0x56780000
That looks like a 2 byte alignment issue, but I cannot figure out why.  I thought my memory boundary math was wrong, but when I set FLASH LENGTH to 524284 (which is what I think it should be), my .map files shows everything shifted for 0x807FFFB address, and shows .crc as a 5 byte section.
I'm on an STM32F101 mcu, which is ARM Cortex-M3.  This doesn't look like endianness issue to me, but maybe I'm not thinking straight...
I tried locating the section in a couple different places in the .ld script, and the only thing that changed was the addition of an ALIGN in the .map showing the next address for the location counter would be 0x08080000, which is correct.
Anyone have an idea on what I'm missing?

If you comment out the definition of uint32_t _Check_Sum in your code, how is the debugger showing it to be a uint32_t?

It feels to me like you're trying to do something that could be solved in an easier way. Why does the CRC value get set in the linker script? This is very odd. Feels like an X/Y problem.

Does changing LONG(_CRC_Value); to QUAD(_CRC_Value); help?

Other inputs to the FLASH memory section may have alignment constraints.  Why do you need to complicate life by making another memory region?  What is your target output? How will you actually calculate the CRC, at run time and at build time? Is the residual zero?  The duplicate link does not care about any of these issues; special cases exist for some specific answers above, but why not use the method referenced in the duplicate?
